# Fabric: can´t acces pathpoints anymore

Tags: javascript, svg, path, fabricjs

I have written a small program, where I move path-point. This was no problem, until I updated to the new Fabrics 2.x.

Here is the code:

```
var boardpath = new fabric.Path('M '+eval(points[0][0]+versatzx)+' '+eval(points[0][1]+versatzy)+
                            ' Q '+eval(manis[0][0]+versatzx)+' '+eval(manis[0][1]+versatzy)+' '+eval(points[1][0]+versatzx)+' '+eval(points[1][1]+versatzy)+
                            ' Q '+eval(manis[1][0]+versatzx)+' '+eval(manis[1][1]+versatzy)+' '+eval(points[2][0]+versatzx)+' '+eval(points[2][1]+versatzy)+
                            ' Q '+eval(manis[2][0]+versatzx)+' '+eval(manis[2][1]+versatzy)+' '+eval(points[3][0]+versatzx)+' '+eval(points[3][1]+versatzy)+
                            ' Q '+eval(manis[3][0]+versatzx)+' '+eval(manis[3][1]+versatzy)+' '+eval(points[4][0]+versatzx)+' '+eval(points[4][1]+versatzy)+
                            ' Q '+eval(manis[4][0]+versatzx)+' '+eval(manis[4][1]+versatzy)+' '+eval(points[5][0]+versatzx)+' '+eval(points[5][1]+versatzy)+
                            ' Q '+eval(versatzx-manis[4][0])+' '+eval(manis[4][1]+versatzy)+' '+eval(versatzx-points[4][0])+' '+eval(points[4][1]+versatzy)+
                            ' Q '+eval(versatzx-manis[3][0])+' '+eval(manis[3][1]+versatzy)+' '+eval(versatzx-points[3][0])+' '+eval(points[3][1]+versatzy)+
                            ' Q '+eval(versatzx-manis[2][0])+' '+eval(manis[2][1]+versatzy)+' '+eval(versatzx-points[2][0])+' '+eval(points[2][1]+versatzy)+
                            ' Q '+eval(versatzx-manis[1][0])+' '+eval(manis[1][1]+versatzy)+' '+eval(versatzx-points[1][0])+' '+eval(points[1][1]+versatzy)+
                            ' Q '+eval(versatzx-manis[0][0])+' '+eval(manis[0][1]+versatzy)+' '+eval(points[0][0]+versatzx)+' '+eval(points[0][1]+versatzy)); //Bezier kurve, keine quadritische

  boardpath.set({ fill: 'white', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 2, opacity: 0.5, selectable: false});
  canvas.add(boardpath);
```

and this is how I access the path-points.

```
boardpath.path[2][3] = 120;
boardpath.path[2][4] = 120;
```

As explained, I´m with Fabrics 1.6.4. and it works. But updating to 2.x ends in total Disaster.
Loading SVGs is also no working with the new version.
Any Idea?
Just realized, it is not working from Fabric 1.7. on. So the change must have been with 1.7. I will dig a bit into the old Fabric changelogs.

Comment: What does "total Desaster" mean exactly? What does "no working" mean. Are there error messages in the browser console?

Comment: Hello Robert, no, no error messages. Total disaster means, nothing is working anymore. I just realized that it is not working from version 1.7. anymore.

Comment: You can check the change log [here](http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes) and [here](http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes-2)

Comment: It was a problem of the Object-Caching, that was introduced with the 1.7 version. Problem solved. At least this problem, more to come.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to make your changes visible in the path.
Path changes are not supported in fabricjs yet, so modifying a nested property of an array does not sort any effect if you do not inform the object that he needs a drawing operation, setting the dirty flag to true.

```
boardpath.path[2][3] = 120;
boardpath.path[2][4] = 120;
boardpath.dirty = true;
```